# Testing empty list [] with Eq type

Tags: haskell

Currently, I am writing a function in Haskell to check a list is symmetric or not.

```
isReflexive :: Eq a => [(a, a)] -> Bool 
isReflexive [] = True
isReflexive xs = and [elem (x, x) xs | x <- [fst u | u <- xs] ++ [snd u | u <- xs]]

test = do
    print(isReflexive [])

main = test
```

The function works fine on the list that is not empty. However, when I test the empty list with the function, it raised an error

> Ambiguous type variable ‘a2’ arising from a use of ‘isReflexive’ prevents the constraint ‘(Eq a2)’ from being solved.
>
> Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a2’ should be.
>
> These potential instances exist:
>
> instance Eq Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
>
> instance Eq Integer  -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp-1.0.2.0:GHC.Integer.Type’
>
> instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Maybe’
>   ...plus 22 others
>
> ...plus 7 instances involving out-of-scope types
>
> (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
>
> • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘(isReflexive [])’
>   How to fix this error?

Comment: Completely unrelated to your problem, only a style comment: consider pattern matching. I think `and [elem (x, x) xs | (u, v) <- xs, x <- [u, v]]` would be a particularly nice example of how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is simply that, in order to apply `isReflexive`, GHC needs to know which type you are using it on.

The type signature of `isReflexive` - `Eq a => [(a, a)] -> Bool` doesn't tell GHC a concrete type that the function works on. That's perfectly fine, and usual, but most often the code that calls the function makes it clear what exactly `a` is in that particular application. That's not so here, because `[]` has itself a polymorphic (and therefore ambiguous) type, `[a]` (for any `a`).

To fix it you simply have to provide a concrete type for your `[]` here, which is consistent with the signature of `isReflexive`. It really doesn't matter what, but an example from many that will work is:

```
test = do
    print(isReflexive ([] :: [(Int, Int)]))
```

(Note that this is exactly what GHC is telling you when it says `Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what 'a2' should be`. 'a2' in that message corresponds to 'a' here, GHC tends to use 'a1', 'a2' etc to refer to all type variables.)