# Haskell ambiguous type variable compiler error when foldMap on empty List

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, compiler-errors, ghc

I'm trying to write a function that flattens nested Lists.

The code:

```
data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]

flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
flatten (Elem e) = [e]
flatten (List l) = foldMap flatten l

main = do
    let c0 = List []
    print $ flatten c0
```

When I try and provide an empty List from main I get a compiler error:

```
Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
```

I am wondering what causes this error and how to fix it.

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: It's exactly as the error message says - GHC can't figure out what the `a` is in `NestedList a` for the value `List []`. To fix, again as GHC says, just give a type annotation, eg `let c0 = (List [] :: NestedList Int)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing empty list \[\] with Eq type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60243815/testing-empty-list-with-eq-type)

Comment: I found this article, and it really helped me learn about this error and others: https://obround.blogspot.com/2020/09/haskell-ghcs-error-messages-explained.html

Answer (score 0):

When you call `print :: (Show a) => a -> IO ()`, the constraint on `Show a` needs to be solved somehow. In your case, the type of `c0` is inferred to be `NestedList a`, which is of course not enough information to solve the `Show [a]` constraint from `print $ flatten c0`.

You solve this problem by adding a type signature to the binding of `c0` to make it monomorphic.